# Importing Google Calendar events from alias addresses

Tags: google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

Usually when you create a new event an invitation email is sent and automatically inserted into the users calendar. In the case the invitation is sent to an alias address Google will not insert the event until the user responds in the Gmail calendar banner.

My problem is how to replicate this process outside of Gmail. I have tried both using "insert" and "import" after parsing the .ICS file but neither work as I expected.

1. For "insert" the event is inserted but as a copy and the organizer of the event is changed to match the current account which it was added to. Even if the organizer was the same it is a copy, which means if the organizer were to move the event or rename it changes would not be reflected in both calendars.
2. For "import" the event is inserted and the organizer is correct but the "privateCopy" flag is set and changing the response status for the attendee doesn't update in the organizers calendar. I guess this is by design since it the docs do say it's a copy.

So my question, how do I add the original/same event in both calendars? I'm confused because the iCalUID is the same whether I use insert or import but regardless the even is not "linked" across the different accounts. I thought the idea with the protocol was that the iCalUID is used for this very purpose but I must be missing something.

Comment: Can you share more details on how you are doing this and the issue you are facing as well as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'm using the Cocoa/Objective-C framework for working with the API. The steps are 1) parse the ICS file sent from the gmail invitation in order to the get the dates, attendee list, organizer iCalUID etc... 2) Use the Insert or Import with the details I got the from the ICS file to upload to the users calendar. What other details can I provide?

Comment: After getting the information you are using the Drive API to insert the events right? Can you provide the code you are using?